# UITableView shows up with frame-based layout but not with auto layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have the following viewController.

```
class CatalogTableViewController: UITableViewController, Storyboarded {
    
    typealias Snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String,String>

    var dataSource: StackTableViewDataSource!
    var suggestionsTableViewDataSource: AutoPopulateSuggestionTableViewDataSource!
    
    var autoSuggestionTableView: UITableView!
    var headerView: StackTableHeaderView!
    var textFieldDelegate = AutoCompletingTextFieldDelegate()
    
    weak var coordinator: MainCoordinator?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view
        configureTableViewDatasource()
        configureHeaderView()
        configureNavigationItem()
        tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
    
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        headerView = StackTableHeaderView(width: tableView.frame.width)
        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
    }

    func configureHeaderView() {
        headerView.typeField.delegate = self
        autoSuggestionTableView = UITableView(frame: .zero)
        autoSuggestionTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(autoSuggestionTableView)
        autoSuggestionTableView.snp.makeConstraints{ (make) in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(50)
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview().offset(100)
            make.left.equalToSuperview()
            make.right.equalToSuperview()
        }
        autoSuggestionTableView.backgroundColor = .gray
        suggestionsTableViewDataSource = AutoPopulateSuggestionTableViewDataSource(tableView: autoSuggestionTableView)
        autoSuggestionTableView.dataSource = suggestionsTableViewDataSource
        autoSuggestionTableView.register(TextCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "someID")
        suggestionsTableViewDataSource.apply(AutoCompleteSuggestionDataModel.snapshot(), animatingDifferences: false)
    }
    
    func configureTableViewDatasource() {
        dataSource = StackTableViewDataSource(tableView: self.tableView)
        self.tableView.register(TextCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: TextCell.identifier)
        dataSource.apply(SkillGroupsDataModel.snapshot(), animatingDifferences: false)
    }
    ....
}
```

My autoSuggestionTableView does not show up at all. However when I change configureHeaderView to this:

```
func configureHeaderView() {
    headerView.typeField.delegate = self
    autoSuggestionTableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 500))
    self.view.addSubview(autoSuggestionTableView)
    autoSuggestionTableView.backgroundColor = .gray
    suggestionsTableViewDataSource = AutoPopulateSuggestionTableViewDataSource(tableView: autoSuggestionTableView)
    autoSuggestionTableView.dataSource = suggestionsTableViewDataSource
    autoSuggestionTableView.register(TextCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "someID")
    suggestionsTableViewDataSource.apply(AutoCompleteSuggestionDataModel.snapshot(), animatingDifferences: false)
}
```

Basically replacing the auto layout with a CGRect frame, it starts showing up. [image]

Why does my auto layout based constraint not show up but the frame does. How can I add an auto-layout based UITableView programmatically on top of my existing view?

Comment: Because you forgot to say `autoSuggestionTableView.translates...`?

Comment: Also all that `layoutIfNeeded` is wrong, delete it.

Comment: Also don't use `loadView`.

Comment: @matt where should I put the view code - setting the headerView of my UITableView if not loadView? I removed autoSuggestionTableView.layoutIfNeeded and added autoSuggestionTableView.        autoSuggestionTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false but still the same issue..

Comment: Use `viewDidLoad`. — Not enough info. I'd need to know more about how your view controller's view gets into the interface.

Comment: Try to start the view setup in viewWillAppear (or viewDidAppear) instead of viewDidLoad.